# change home page after first visit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now my project defaults to Home/Index as my sites start page. I want to make it so the first time someone comes to site they go to Home/FirstTime and all subsequent times they return to site they go to Home/Index

I have this code in RouteConfig.cs in App_Start folder

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );

    }
}
```

I am guessing I need to add a route for Home/FirstTime, but I dont know how to store the info on weather they have been to site previsouly.

Comment: Is the user authenticated before loading this page?  If so, you could set a flag in a database that you can check upon login.  If this page is not loaded after the user has authenticated, there is no guaranteed way, but cookies will work 90% of the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a cookie to identify if the user is the first time visitor.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string cookieName = "NotFirstTime";
        if(this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains(cookieName ))
        {
            // not first time 
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            // first time 
            // add a cookie.
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
            cookie.Value = "anything you like: date etc.";
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            // redirect to the page for first time visit.
            return View("FirstTime");
        }
    }
```

There are more settings for a cookie that you can control, like expiration etc. But you should know the direction now.

Comment: cookies can be cleared ... in that case again user will see the first page.

Comment: @Guanxi - umm yes cookies can be cleared, but can you suggest an alternative to this answer?

Comment: If you want to store the visited info in your server, consider recording the IP address of your visitor. But it has its own problem, like many users may come from the same IP.

Comment: @Blaise - IP address is virtually useless considering all the the proxies and forwarding going on by ISPs.

Comment: Agree. IP Address has its own limitation. Cookie is the most obvious way even though it can be cleared at the client side. But it will sufficiently serve the goal of dan_vitch.